# How do I handle a definition that has no neutral term?

Tags: terminology

The financial application I am building contains data which is a number that corresponds with two terms. It works like this:

- `number > 0 = overspend`
- `number < 0 = underspend`

Unfortunately the overspend/underspend terms do not have a neutral term, like `nospend` or `whateverspend`. Now I'm unsure about how to save this data in for example a database column. What name do I give to this database column? Or how do I handle it in my back-end? `double <...spend> = // a number`?

So, like the question says: How do I handle a definition in my application that does not have a neutral term, but either a positive one, or a negative one?

Comment: Are you asking us *what to do* (e.g. defining one column or several) or merely *what to call something* (e.g. `nospend` or `over_or_under_spend`)?

Comment: Well I'm asking how to handle this situation. Of course it would be nice if someone knows a neutral term for this, but I'm pretty sure that a situation like this occurs for other terms as well. `over_or_under_spend` would be a solution, but it suddenly becomes a very long variable.

Comment: Would the close-voter be so nice to explain why this question should be closed? Thank you.

Comment: This seems more like a [user experience stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: @Philipp No it does not. Because in the UI I am able to show the user whatever the number is. If the number is > 0, the user will see the number, with the `overspend` prefix. If the number is < 0, the user will see the number with the `underspend` prefix. The whole point of this question is to figure out what term I can use when I do **not** know what the number is.

Comment: You need to ask the people who are paying you to write the application what they want it called.  We can't answer that.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't save the overspend/underspend flag. You would save "number". Then you can always check if it is positive, negative or 0 in query/view or in business logic.

If you save both "number" *and* the overspend/underspend flag then you have redundant data in the database with is bad for several reasons, most importantly you open the possibility that they could get out of sync (eg. "number" is updated but you forget to update the flag).

If you have say "budget" and "expenditure" as two columns, then you don't need to also save the difference between these two, which seem to be what "number" is.

Comment: I currently do not save a flag, nor do I plan to do so. The whole point of this question is how to name the "number" variable in code/database design. I currently name it `overspend`, but this is not a good solution, because if the number is negative, it will actually say `double overspend = <underspend number>`.

Comment: @Jelle - you just say "number", but what does this number represent then? If you have say "budget" and "expenditure" as two column, then you don't need to also save the difference between these two.

Comment: It represent the `overspend` or `underspend` of a project. For the sake of simplicity, you can compare it to either `profit` or `waste`.

Comment: @Jelle: But how do you know this value? Surely this is the result of some calculation, eg. budget minus expense.

Comment: Yes this is the case. And I already know that you want to say 'Don't save this number, it is the result of a calculation.' But unfortunately, this number is part of a report, so it must be saved.

Comment: @Jelle: "this number is part of a report, so it must be saved" - why do you have to save it? Don't you generate the report from the database?

Comment: we can go on like this, explaining my application, but it has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @Jelle: The name of the column should reflect the *business purpose* of the value. If it doesn't have a clear purpose, then nobody can help you name the column, except by random guessing. You need to take a step back and ask yourself why the naming is not obvious.

Comment: Simply said, it is a monthly report where a manual action is required by a project manager to 'approve' the overspend/underspend value, so the history of over/underspend values can be viewed. This can't be done by a 'on-the-fly' calculation because budgets and estimations shift all the time.

Comment: I would probably call it something like "ApprovedBudgetAdjustment". But I do think approving a budget adjustment is the same as a approving a new budget, and I think it makes more sense to store the new approved value rather than the delta. But it may depend on your particular business.

Comment: thinking up new terms would be great, but this is not possble unfortunately. Underspend/overspend are company-wide known definitions, and when I introduce something like "ApprovedBudgetAdjustment" no one will know what I'm talking about. When I asked this question I was hoping there was something to neutralize the terms underspend and overspend. So I think I'll just go with the current situation, which Duroth explained in his answer. Thanks for your answer & comments anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Name the variable as if it's always positive. Having a negative value already implies the opposite situation. So, in your case, use `overspend`.

For example; a negative value in a variable called **profit** implies *loss* rather than actual *profit*. A negative value in **time_until_X** implies X already happened.

Comment: This is the way I'm currently using it, so unless there won't be a better answer, I will continue to do so.

Comment: This is actually a good advice. Even Chapter 11 of Code Complete doesn't address an issue like that, and the "always positive" rule goes well with the "always write an if in the positive" way. +1.

Answer (score -1):

You could name your column "Spend" which contains "under" when number < 0, "over" when number > 0, otherwise NULL.

Comment: The problem with that is that it 'spend' also means 'expenses', so it could actually bring confusion.